# Weird Behavior From wx.FileDialog

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

Ok folks, here's a weird one.

Theres' a GUI (in wxPython) which allows files to be attached.  The file paths are saved to class attribute `self.pathList`.  These paths are displayed on the GUI and edited with two functions (bound to buttons); `OnAttach()` and `OnView()`.  The first, as the name implies, allows the user to select files, while the second allows the user to see a list of those files and choose which ones to delete.

There are two problems:

- [SOLVED] The items are added to `self.pathList` *without any regard for sorting*.  It doesn't matter if or where `sorted()` is applied, the list is never sorted.  We test this by selecting 100 text files named "1.txt", "2.txt", and so on.  The order seems random.  The full code of the two functions is below, but the line in question is this:

  `self.pathList = list(set(self.pathList + [str(path) for path in sorted(dlg.GetPaths())]))`

Again, it doesn't matter where `sorted` is applied (or if its there at all), the result is the same.  Both lines below return the same `self.pathList`:

```
self.pathList = list(set(self.pathList + [str(path) for path in dlg.GetPaths()]))
self.pathList = sorted(list(set(self.pathList + [str(path) for path in dlg.GetPaths()])))
```

- Removing items from the list seems to fail if more than 3/4 of attachments are selected. *Weird, right?*  I have no explanation for why this is happening, but its pretty consistent. The specific error is `IndexError: pop index out of range`

Hopefully someone can make sense of this.  Thanks in advance

```
def OnAttach(self, event, viewattBtn):
    """Select a File"""
    self.dirname = ''
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.OPEN|wx.MULTIPLE|wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.pathList = list(set(self.pathList + [str(path) for path in sorted(dlg.GetPaths())]))
        for path in self.pathList:
            self.fileNameList.append(path.split('\\')[-1]) 
        self.fileNameList = list(set(self.fileNameList))    #Applying sorted() here fixes the first issue
        self.att.SetLabel('\n'.join(self.fileNameList))
        self.vbox.Layout()
        self.panel.FitInside()
    if self.pathList != []: viewattBtn.Enable(True)
    return viewattBtn
    dlg.Destroy()  

def OnView(self, event, viewattBtn):
    dlg = wx.MultiChoiceDialog(self, "Attachments (Select attachments and push 'OK' to delete)", "", self.fileNameList, wx.OK|wx.CANCEL)   
    if options.diagMode: print self.fileNameList
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        selections = reversed(sorted(dlg.GetSelections()))
        selections = [self.fileNameList[index] for index in selections]              
        for item in selections:
            pathIndex = selections.index(item)
            self.pathList.pop(pathIndex)
            self.fileNameList.remove(item)   
        self.att.SetLabel('\n'.join(self.fileNameList))
        self.vbox.Layout() 
        self.panel.FitInside()
        if self.fileNameList == []: viewattBtn.Enable(False)
        return viewattBtn
    dlg.Destroy
```

**EDIT:** The first problem was fixed by sorted `fileNameList` on the marked line

Comment: Here comes the newbie: you have `self.pathList = list(set(` and sets are unordered, so shouldn't it be normal that the list isn't sorted?

Comment: Same for `self.fileNameList = list(set(`

Comment: (sorry I mean **I** am the newbie)

Comment: You're right, but sorting on the outside of ```list(set(``` didn't help either

Comment: Did you try printing the list right after the sorting statement? Is there possibly another piece of code where they get mixed up again?

Comment: The list is immediately set as the label of ```self.att```, and the order does not change

Comment: @wnnmaw: You didn't answer the important part of Roberto's question: Did you try printing the list right after setting it, or not?

Comment: Also, I notice that each time you come here, you're appending a new list onto the end of an existing one. Is it possible that it's not actually in random order, but rather just a bunch of segments, each segment individually sorted, but the segments themselves in order of creation?

Comment: So its now sorted, because I sorted ```fileNameList``` after it was created. Not sure why this works since it was based off of a sorted list.  So that's fixed now!  The other issue still persists

Comment: No no wait a sec, of course the Label is sorted when you sort fileNameList, that's where the labels come from. Was the actual question why the label wasn't in alphabetical order? (like an XY problem?)

Comment: The question has two parts, why was the list unsorted (solved), and why and I getting an index error only when I try to remove large portions of the list

Answer (score 1):

For your first issue, the problem is that you're creating a `set` out of the sorted list. Sets have no defined order; in fact, the order is *documented* to be arbitrary.

The solution is to just not create a `set` in the first place.

If you need to eliminate duplicates, you can use a recipe like `unique_everseen` from the `itertools` docs, or use an `OrderedSet` class of some kind. If you don't need to eliminate dups, just use the list as-is:

```
self.pathList = self.pathList + [str(path) for path in sorted(dlg.GetPaths())]
```

(Also, if you *did* want a set, you probably wouldn't want to convert that set to a list and add it to another list; you'd want to just keep it as a set in the first place.)

---

For your second issue, I'm not sure what your code is trying to do, but it's almost certainly doing things completely wrong.

First, you *never* want to iterate over a list and then search for the value's index. That does the wrong thing if there are any duplicates, and it's very slow, and it's very complicated. Just keep the index around:

```
    for index, item in enumerate(selections):
```

Second, I don't think the indexes in `selections` have anything to do with the indexes in `pathList` and `fileNameList`, in which case using the indexes doesn't work right in the first place.

But even if the indexes *were* the same at the start, every time you `pop` something out of the list, all of the remaining elements shift up one, so the indexes are no longer right after the first `pop`.

I think it would be better to reorganize your data structure—instead of keeping a bunch of lists, keep one list for whatever the thing is that needs to have a defined order, and keep everything else as dicts, using the values from that first list as keys.

Comment: Ok, so your fist bit doesn't apply, check the comment to mark ransom's answer or an explanation why. Eventually I'll update the post to show that.  I mostly agree with the second bit, but your example for loop broke (```TypeError: enumerate() takes no arguments (1 given)```)

Comment: @wnnmaw: If you're getting that `TypeError`, you've somehow replaced the builtin `enumerate` with a different function with the same name. Don't do that.

Comment: @wnnmaw: And if you've replaced `enumerate` with some random function of no arguments that does something besides enumerating, I wouldn't be surprised if you've also replaced `sorted` with some random function that does something besides sorting, which would explain your other problem.

Comment: @abarnet I just ran a search of my file, there are no other variables called ```enumerate```

Comment: @wnnmaw: Add a `print(enumerate.__doc__)`, and I'm willing to bet it's not the standard `enumerate` docs. You can `import inspect` and add a `print(inspect.getsourcefile(enumerate))` to see where you defined it. There is no way the builtin `enumerate` can give you that error.

Comment: So I added ```print enumerate.__doc__``` and you are right, ```enumerate``` got overwritten.  It appears that this was done by ```threading```. Is this a known issue?  I feel like I should report this somewhere.

Comment: @wnnmaw: Many modules, including some in the stdlib, are not designed to be used with `from foo import *`. It's not a bug that `threading.enumerate` exists, any more than it's a bug that `anydbm.open` exists. Just `import threading` and use qualified names, the same way you're already doing with `wx`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `set` will reorder your items, unsorting them. Don't do that, or sort *after* you've converted the set back to a list.

As you remove items from `pathList` the position of items in that list will change, and will no longer correspond to the numbers you're getting from `selections`. After you're removed enough items chances are one of the indexes will be beyond the size of the list.

Comment: So in ```onAttach``` I added ```sorted()``` to the very outside of the list creation to no avail.  As for your second point, that should be taken care of by sorting selections and putting it in reverse order.  This means the removal starts from the end of the list and never disturbs the index of previous entries.

Comment: @wnnmaw, you're sorting before you've converted the selections to indexes, not after. They're likely still in the wrong order.